# Retirar aspas de strings em array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

Como posso retirar as aspas simples do resultado?

Usuário digita `teste` e tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd> para sair.

O programa captura as teclas digitadas e salva dígito por dígito em uma lista.

A lista é preenchida assim:

```
lista ---> ["'t'", "'e'", "'s'", "'t'", "'e'", 'Key.esc']
```

O resultado da impressão usando o `''.join(lista)` fica assim:

> Resultado ---> 't''e''s''t''e'Key.esc

Eu desejo que o resultado final seja assim:

> testeKey.esc

Código:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key): #tecla pressionada
    lista.append(str(key))

def on_release(key): #ao soltar a tecla
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False #interrompe programa

lista = []

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

print('lista ---> ', lista)
print('Resultado ---> ', ''.join(lista))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) e substituir todas as aspas por uma string vazia (que é o mesmo que removê-las):

```
print('Resultado ---> ', ''.join(lista).replace("'", ""))
```

Com isso, as aspas simples (`'`) são eliminadas do resultado final.

Se quiser, também pode usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) e fazer o `replace` em cada elemento da lista separadamente:

```
print('Resultado ---> ', ''.join(s.replace("'", "") for s in lista))
```

Ambos imprimem:

> Resultado --->  testeKey.esc

Embora neste caso eu ache a primeira opção mais simples e direta.

---

#### E se o próprio caractere `'` for digitado?

Fiz um teste digitando `a`, depois `'`, depois <kbd>ESC</kbd>, e a lista fica assim:

```
["'a'", '"\'"', 'Key.esc']
```

Repare que o caractere `'` fica entre aspas duplas.

Então o `replace` acima não funciona, pois ele também remove o `'` que foi digitado e o resultado final fica `a""Key.esc`.

Para corrigir isso, podemos criar uma função para tratar este caso especial:

```
def replace_exceto_aspas(s):
    if '"\'"' == s:
        return "'"
    return s.replace("'", "")
```

Ou seja, se for o próprio caractere `'` entre aspas duplas (`"`), eu retorno uma aspas simples. Senão, removo as aspas simples.

Agora é só usar a *list comprehension*, chamando esta função para todos os elementos da lista, e por fim juntando tudo com `join`:

```
print('Resultado ---> ', ''.join(replace_exceto_aspas(s) for s in lista))
```

O resultado será:

> Resultado --->  a'Key.esc

---

#### Alternativa

Mas talvez seja mais simples mudar a forma como você pega o caractere que está sendo digitado:

```
def on_press(key):  # tecla pressionada
    try:
        lista.append(key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        lista.append(str(key))
```

Se a tecla pressionada tiver o atributo `char` - como é o caso dos caracteres alfanuméricos - o seu valor é adicionado na lista (somente o valor do próprio caractere, sem as aspas). Caso seja uma outra tecla não-alfanumérica (como o <kbd>ESC</kbd>), ele cai no `except` e é adicionado o valor conforme você já estava fazendo.

Assim, você pode fazer simplesmente `''.join(lista)`, sem precisar se preocupar em remover as aspas (não precisa mais do `replace`, nem da função que criei acima).

Comment: Agradeço sua ajuda e disponibilização de tempo para responder essa questão. Sua resposta foi precisa e, coincidentemente, eu passei a usar a alternativa indicada. Obrigado. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apenas use o método `.replace()` se ocorrerem durante todo o processo, ou `.strip()` se ocorrerem apenas no início e/ou finalização:

```
a = '"sajdkasjdsak" "asdasdasds"' 

a = a.replace('"', '')
'sajdkasjdsak asdasdasds'

# ou, se ocorrerem apenas no início e no fim ...
a = a.strip('\"')
'sajdkasjdsak" "asdasdasds'

# ou, se ocorrerem apenas no início ...
a = a.lstrip('\"')

# ou, se ocorrerem apenas no final ...
a = a.rstrip('\"')
```

Comment: Agradeço sua atenção. Eu desejo que o resultado final da impressão seja assim: testeKey.esc

Answer (score 0):

Se usar o `replace` como os amigos indicaram não for a sua intenção você também pode usar [expressões regulares](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) usando a função `sub` do modulo `re`.

No caso seu código ficaria assim:

```py
print('lista ---> ', lista)
lista = re.sub(r'\s', '', lista)
print('Resultado ---> ', lista)
```

> **Nota:** Não se esqueça de importar o módulo `re` no seu código.
>   Caso não o tenha instalado use o comando `pip`: No terminal, rode `pip3 install re`
>   Pronto, seu módulo está instalado. Agora é só usá-lo :)